# How long does a Dutch family immigration application take?

Tags: resident-permit, netherlands

My wife, who is a Dutch national, has applied for my immigration in the Netherlands. 
 I am from Pakistan and am waiting for the process to complete while studying for the Dutch Civic integration exam.

How long does the process usually take?

After I get my civic integration exam result, if I pass, how long will it take for the embassy to process my MVV?